# Validation score not matching predicted score on XGBoost script

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, cross-validation, xgboost

I've been learning how to use scikit learn using the Santander customer satisfaction competition on kaggle:

https://www.kaggle.com/c/santander-customer-satisfaction

I've run grid search to tune the parameters of the XGBoost model and get a predicted roc_auc score of 0.83. When I test the winning model against the hold out set it seems that the model doesn't have any predictive power and gives as score of 0.50. I must be making an error in my script, but can't find what's going wrong and can't fathom where to look.

My training script is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from scipy.stats import randint, uniform
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score


# reproducibility
seed = 342
np.random.seed(seed)

train_data = pd.read_csv("./train.csv")
test_data = pd.read_csv("./test.csv")

array = train_data.values

# Split-out validation dataset
X = array[:,0:369].astype(float)
Y = array[:,370].astype(int)
validation_size = 0.20
seed = 7
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=validation_size, random_state=seed)

params_grid = {
    'max_depth': [1, 2, 3],
    'n_estimators': [5, 10, 25, 50],
    'learning_rate': np.linspace(1e-16, 1, 3)
}

# params fixed
params_fixed = {
    'objective': 'binary:logistic',
    'silent': 1
}

# grid search
grid_search = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=XGBClassifier(params_fixed, seed=seed, nthread=-1),
    param_grid=params_grid,
    cv=10,
    verbose=1,
    scoring='roc_auc'
)

grid_search.fit(X_train, Y_train)

print grid_search.grid_scores_
print grid_search.best_score_
print grid_search.best_estimator_
```

This gives the following output (I've omitted the long list of models):

```
0.83303461644
XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, colsample_bylevel=1, colsample_bytree=1,
       gamma=0, learning_rate=0.5, max_delta_step=0, max_depth=3,
       min_child_weight=1, missing=None, n_estimators=25, nthread=-1,
       objective='binary:logistic', reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1,
       scale_pos_weight=1, seed=7, silent=True, subsample=1)
```

Here's the script used to calculate the score on the hold out data:

```
import numpy as np
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from scipy.stats import randint, uniform
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score


# reproducibility
seed = 342
np.random.seed(seed)

train_data = pd.read_csv("./train.csv")
test_data = pd.read_csv("./test.csv")

array = train_data.values

# Split-out validation dataset
X = array[:,0:369].astype(float)
Y = array[:,370].astype(int)
validation_size = 0.20
seed = 7
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=validation_size, random_state=seed)

watchlist  = [(X_train, Y_train), (X_validation, Y_validation)]

model = XGBClassifier(
        base_score=0.5, 
        colsample_bylevel=1, 
        colsample_bytree=1,
        gamma=0, 
        learning_rate=0.5, 
        max_delta_step=0, 
        max_depth=3,
        min_child_weight=1, 
        missing=None, 
        n_estimators=25, 
        nthread=-1,
        objective='binary:logistic', 
        reg_alpha=0, 
        reg_lambda=1,
        scale_pos_weight=1, 
        seed=7, 
        silent=True, 
        subsample=1
)

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, eval_metric="auc", eval_set=watchlist, verbose=True)

model.fit(X_train, Y_train)

predictions = model.predict(X_validation)

print roc_auc_score(Y_validation, predictions)
```

This outputs 0.503777444213, which is contrary to expectations which are that is should output a lower score, but one that is considerably closer to 0.83.

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

**Update following suggestion to plot learning curves**

Plotting the learning curves (assuming I've interpreted correctly) produces the following chart:

[image: Train & Test learning curves]
Values are from a watchlist defined as per above, I've edited the code where I've added this in. I've omitted the code for the plot.

From what I can tell this suggests that over-fitting isn't to blame, and I suspect the error is in the way I have generated the calculation of the validation in the first instance, but that's just my feeling, I don't yet fully understand what I'm working with.

For completeness, here's what I used to plot the learning curves, for better or worse. I've realised some of the labels should have been re-written from where I found the code:

```
epochs = len(results['validation_0']['auc'])
x_axis = range(0, epochs)
y_axis = range(0, 1)
# plot log loss
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
ax.plot(x_axis, results['validation_0']['auc'], label='Train')
ax.plot(x_axis, results['validation_1']['auc'], label='Test')
ax.legend()
pyplot.ylabel('auc')
pyplot.show()
# plot classification error
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
ax.plot(x_axis, results['validation_0']['auc'], label='Train')
ax.plot(x_axis, results['validation_1']['auc'], label='Test')
ax.legend()
pyplot.ylabel('Classification Error')
pyplot.title('XGBoost Classification Error')
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: seems like overfitting...plot the learning curves to see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks @tihom I'll look into how to do that.

Comment: @tihom - I've added in code and a chart to demonstrate the learning curves (assuming I've interpreted your suggestion correctly). Am I right in thinking that this doesn't in fact point to over fitting now, or have I missed the point?

Comment: Can you post the code for producing your test errors?

Comment: Can you be more specific? I thought I'd posted it all.

Comment: What is size of the dataset? i mean number of rows

Comment: train.csv has 76,020 rows in it, which is the set that's split into train/validation sets

Comment: @goose couple of questions on the learning curve. Is the training data size only `25` rows? I say this cause the  x-axis shows a max of `25`. That sample sample size is very small for a feature size of `369`. Second is the y-axis plotting error or accuracy, It is labeled error but I think it is accuracy since it is increasing and gets close to 0.85.

Comment: The training set is a lot larger (76k rows). What the code suggests is along the x-axis is epochs. The y-axis plots roc auc scoring. I've plotted the code I used to create the chart in case it's of consequence.

Comment: I've still not solved this. I have three hypotheses: (1) in-sufficient data-cleaning - I've not done any, but note that this may be necessary as per https://www.kaggle.com/gouxute1/santander-customer-satisfaction/xgboost-and-simple-data-cleaning/code . I had planned to come back to learn how to clean data, perhaps the data set I'm working with requires processing before any model accuracy can be obtained. (2) over-fitting, but this would seem to be unlikely as the training curves show that the validation set doesn't score so much worse than the training set (assuming I've correctly executed)

Comment: (3) lastly my initial theory is that I've made some trivial but hidden error with my implementation of scikit-learn and xgboost. I'm relatively in-experienced with both libraries and in the last step when I call model.predict and roc_auc_score I've come up with this code myself. Even though it seems intuitively right, this is where my problems appear to begin.

Comment: When I call print roc_auc_score(Y_validation, model.predict_proba(X_validation)[:,1], average='macro') instead of print roc_auc_score(Y_validation, predictions) I get a score that closely matches what the model testing suggests I should get. I'm still churning through this in my head, but am pretty sure that I've found the root cause.

Comment: OP did you ever figure this out?